# Django CSRF cookie not set: using Ajax Cross site

Tags: django, ajax, csrf, http-status-code-403, django-csrf

I have two parts of my code first is a **frontend (no framework/library)** running on `localhost:3000` via simple `python HTTP server` and a `Django server` running on `localhost:8080`, what's happening in here is **the frontend is making a cross-site POST request to Django server** but its been getting a **Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)** error. I know this problem has been asked about so many times but I don't seem to find a solution.

I don't have any experience requesting a **POST** call in Django like this, not using **DRF** but **endpoints** of our own.

### **The Problem Code:**

firstly the **frontend** shall make a get request for a **csrf token** to `/api/csrf/`

#### views.py:

```
def get_csrf(request):
    # print(get_token(request))
    return JsonResponse({
        'detail': 'CSRF cookie set',
        'X-CSRFToken': get_token(request)
        })
```

After getting the value, the token is assigned to the **cookie** and a **hidden element** via

#### main.js:

```
success: function (response, status, xhr) {
      $('.csrftoken').attr('value', response['X-CSRFToken']);
       setCookie("csrftoken", response['X-CSRFToken']);
}
```

The code above works fine and we get the value, at the start, it was like this but was not working so I changed it like:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader("X-CSRFToken") -> response['X-CSRFToken']
```

Now whenever the **frontend** makes a **POST** call to the back end with `header:{ 'X-CSRFToken': token}` running on `localhost:8080` it gets `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) 403`

#### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders,
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
]
```

#### The **POST request**:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
      },
      url: "/api/userdetails/",
      data: JSON.stringify(somedata),
      ...
      ...
})
```

#### What I have tried so far:

I have tried to get the **csrftoken** via-

```
# from the hidden element
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('.csrftoken').value;
# from the cookie
const csrftoken = getCCookie('csrftoken');
# from the name
const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
```

***All of these successfully retrieve the value,and i can see the value in request header header but still django says there is no csrftoken***
As the doc says while using the below code in setting one must get the value from the hidden element, again I tried it as well with it without it:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) says to try this as well:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
  // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
```

But no successful attempts here, what is wrong with the code? and how should I get past through it.

Comment: `successfully retrieve the value, but unable to put it in the header` please clarify: do you have this value in the **request**? Use browser devtools to check what was passed in the request. If true, then check this option value in your settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#csrf-header-name

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes, you are right the value is in the request header as X-CSRFToken and the csrf header is set to default in the settings.py, I should correct that portion of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include `{% csrf_token %}` in you django html template. This will create hidden input html tag with name 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'.

Your javascript code which sets `var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();` must be included after the html code is rendered otherwise var csrftoken is set to null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django-view-ajax-handle' %}" id="ajax-function-id" name="ajax-function-name">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

// GET CSRF_TOKEN AFTER HTML
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

<script>
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ajax-function-id").submit(function (event) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $('[name="ajax-function-name"]').attr("action"),
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
      },
      success: function (data) {
        // handle_success
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```